# Pandas setting a limit on duplicate results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
       Domain         URL                               Importance
1      google.com     google.com/example/1/file.exe     1
2      microsoft.com  microsoft.com/example/1/file.exe  3
3      apple.com      apple.com/example/1/file.exe      4
4      google.com     google.com/example/2/file.exe     1
5      google.com     google.com/example/3/file.exe     2
6      apple.com      apple.com/example/2/file.exe      3
...    ...            ...                               ...
1000   google.com     google.com/example/500/file.exe   2
```

All the urls will always be unique, however there are overlaps with the domains. 
Importance levels are pre-assigned to the rows in the dataframe, with 1 being the most important and 4 being the lowest priority.

I'm looking for a good "Pandaic" way to filter the dataframe so that there can be a maximum of 50 urls per domain, ordered by level of highest importance (1>4). Then for a total maximum of 750 urls, again having been filtered by level of importance before cutting off the bottom.

Comment: You want to look at `groupby('Domain').head(50)` for maximal `50` rows per domain, then `head(750)` for maximum `750` total. Also, `sort_values('Importance')` to sort.

Comment: I'm currently thinking of making a list of all unique domains, then making dataframes for each unique domain in that list, and populating the data for each unique domain dataframe with its relevant data.

I'd then order the dataframes by level of importance and use head(50) to cut down the results in each dataframe,

The plan is then to merge all dataframes back together,  order it by importance one more, then cut off the results at 750. 

Does this logic make sense? 
Also does anyone know how to make many different dataframes with dataframe names taken from a list

Comment: That would be very slow.

Comment: Di you know a more efficient way to design that, potentially? Thanks for the help here btw